# xv-like image viewer that lets me annotate/mark images?

Tags: images

When I'm viewing many images w/ xv (sometimes in "visual schnauzer" 
mode), I sometimes want to "bookmark" or annotate a given image.

I don't think xv can do this, but is there another xv-like image 
viewer that can?

Is it possible to add "programmable hot-keys" to xv so that typing 
certain letters lets you call external commands (eg, "emacs (filename 
of picture you are viewing)")?

I think that xv has a 'mark' feature, but that's more internal, and 
the marks go away after I close xv.

I realize I could just open a text editor and make notes myself 
(typing in the filename by hand or maybe using xv's "info" window), 
but is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Please define: Annotate. Do you want to write on the image? Into a text-file with the same name?

Comment: I want to annotate into a file named [imagename].txt, not alter the image itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [sxiv](https://github.com/muennich/sxiv) will let you do what you want. You can modify the configuration *relatively* easily, including adding bindings that will execute a shell command. In particular, you might look at [this fork](https://github.com/kaihendry/sxiv/tree/tags) for an example that could do what you're talking about.

I don't know, though, of any application as simple as xv that will do what you want out of the box.

Comment: Thanks! It turns out that qiv (which is referenced in sxiv's man page) already has "USER-DEFINED KEYBOARD ACTIONS" AND the 'a' keyboard option copies the selected image to a special directory. Bliss!

Comment: OK, qiv has no thumbnail feature, so I'm now in love with feh (also mentioned in the sxiv manpage)

Comment: The link to the fork doesn't work anymore. Do you have an updated link?